# How to assign an ng-class to a column of jqxgrid in a controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I have imported necessary scripts for angular, bootstrap and jqwidgets. I wish to hide a particular column of the jqgrid using the class hidden-lg in the grid's controller.

```
     $scope.gridWidth = "100%";
     $scope.columns = [
        {text: 'Col1', dataField: 'val1', width:'30%'},
        {text: 'Col2', dataField: 'val2', cellsformat: 'c2', cellsalign: 'left',width:'30%', template: '<div data-ng-class="hidden-lg"></div>'},
        {text: 'Col3', dataField: 'val3', cellsformat: 'c2', cellsalign: 'left',width:'40%'}
     ];
```

Regards,

Comment: well you can use `hidden:true` for the specific column.

Comment: well, I want to hide the column only when the page is rendered in a particular device [say a tablet : hidden-md]. using this class of the bootstrap I can I hide the column in any "medium" class devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research on this .. i could find out that it can be solved like this.

```
 $scope.columns = [
    {text: 'Col1', dataField: 'val1', width:'30%'},
    {text: 'Col2', dataField: 'val2', cellsformat: 'c2', cellsalign: 'left',width:'30%', cellclassname:"hidden-xs",classname:"hidden-xs"},
    {text: 'Col3', dataField: 'val3', cellsformat: 'c2', cellsalign: 'left',width:'40%'}
 ];
```

cellclassname:"hidden-xs",classname:"hidden-xs" hides the particular column in a particular device.

However now I am struck with another problem... I see white empty space after hiding the middle column... I have empty space between 1st and 3rd column.

Please suggest help...